# Install HUE or Spark on local PC and ssh root to access Cloudera of my company?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, cloudera

Sorry for my rookie question. I was just wondering if I could ever install a HUE or Spark on my personal PC at home and ssh (through openvpn) the Cloudera of my company? It's just I have no computer science backgroud in the past and I really need to retrieve some data and start my data analysis work. And I'm not very comfortable with terminal view of HIVE or IMPALA which is already installed on the server.

Thanks in advance! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because Cloudera will warn that spark or hue nodes will lost ping for your network latency.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It'll save much time for me otherwise I'll be googling forever.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible if **your PC is added as a node on the same hadoop cluster**.

Post which you may install HUE as a service on it.

As stated in the other answer, network latency could create issues.

---

Alternatively if your company is using Cloudera Distribution, it should already have Hue installed which you may use over the network using putty(with X11 forwarding) or any similar tool.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately my company will not allow to add my PC as a node. But I'll ask them if HUE is already there.  Right now I am trying to accustom myself to Linux environment and terminal interactions, which is not easy since Windows has been the only OS I ever used.

Comment: @JYWQ oh.. I missed out the word "**company**". So then use Hue, it has a good interface for querying and scheduling etc..